# "Съедание" части элементов формы

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу программу с интерфейсом, сделал что-то подобное. Вид из редактора Студии:[image]

Всё, что в красном прямоугольнике - помещено в StackPanel, а ниже идет ListBox Код:

```
<StackPanel ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="28,29,25,387" Height="24">
        <Image Source="Images/Command-Undo.png" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Image Source="Images/Command-Redo.png" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="280"  Text="" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24">
            <Image Source="Images/refresh.png"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="167" MouseEnter="SearchedBox_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="SearchedBox_MouseLeave" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Однако, при запуске приложения видим это:[image]

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

---

P.S. Увеличение высоты StackPanel с 25 до 45 ошибку правит, но выглядит это странно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы задаете отступ снизу у StackPanel — 387. Здесь  `Margin="28,29,25,387"` правьте последнее число.

Comment: Ключевая ошибка в том, что вы используете дизайнер/конструктор форм

Comment: Если можно отказаться от `StackPanel`, то лучше сделать это

Comment: @maxwell Помогло, оформите как ответ.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Так то так, однако без дизайнера жизнь боль, удобства, (как и скилла в WPF)) 0. Почему вы не рекомендуете использовать StackPanel?

Comment: без дизайнера жизнь намного проще и удобнее

Comment: Не рекомендую, так как это была одна из рекомендаций которые я получил в [WPF чате](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf). Неоднократно возникают вопросы связанные с непониманием как работает `StackPanel`. В том числе и тут. Если хотите могу поискать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часть элементов "съедается", потому что вы задаете отступ от нижнего края в свойстве `Margin` у `StackPanel` — 387.

Лучше не использовать конструктор форм, а научиться писать разметку самому во избежание подобных ситуаций.